# Melted gasket on moka pot. How do I clean it?

Tags: moka, equipment, coffee-machines, cleaning

I was running a water cycle through my moka pot and completely forgot it on the stove. When I came back in the kitchen after 30-45 minutes it smelled of burnt rubber and I found that the gasket had completely melted when I took it apart. How do I clean it, and can I even still use it?

Answer (score 2):

The gasket in Moka pots need to be replaced every now and then, depending on how often you use the pot. If your gasket was damaged, then you should definitely replace it, for safety reasons.

If you can simply take it out, do so. If it’s stuck, you may need to gently (!) scrape it off with a flat screwdriver or knife, but be careful not to damage the metal. While you are at it, I’d also recommend to take out the screen on the underside of the top compartment (if the gasket is caked on you’ll need to do so in any case), using the occasion for a bit of cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Stephie's answer: probably you'll have to remove the last residuals of rubber with some iron wool. After you've cleaned thorougly the gasket seat, you can use again your moka, but the first one or two coffee will be awful due to the "aroma" of burt rubber. Just run one or two cycle with water only (no coffee) and you'll be fine.

Do not use any solvent or alchool, for they'll ruin your pot forever.